# can websphere application server 9 be installed side by side with 8.5.5?

Tags: websphere, application-server

Can websphere application server 9 be installed side by side with 8.5.5 on the same developer box?

We want to be able to still continue maintaining our older J2EE projects.

Thanks,
Bert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the only restriction in this area is with some of the obscure separately installable "Edge components" bundled with some editions of WebSphere.  You will find that even the port assignment is coordinated across the two installs/versions.

Comment: Thank you. The profile creation did not go as you suggested, it wanted to create AppSrv01 which existed already. I had to change that to AppSrv09 and manually modify each of the port settings.